# Issues with creating Web Socket server on different port?

Tags: c#, websocket

We are currently on Windows 2008 and need to use Web sockets. We cannot move to IIS8 with Windows 8 or Windows 2012 which has native web sockets support built into IIS.

So we are thinking about using web sockets via a third party web socket server.

However, it was mentioned that we would have to use another port other than port 80 which we are currently using for our web server app.

Clearly using another port may cause issues with some installations as they will have to open up the ports on their network.

So, what are my options?
Can I take a Web socket call on 80 and reroute it so it is handled as a websocket call?

We really do not want to move to Windows 8 or windows 2012.

Comment: I may be wrong here but http.sys that comes with Windows 8 allows two different process to listen on the same port. If there is no option to do this on Win 2008 you'd have to put some kind of  proxy in front that could split and route the calls appropriately. This proxy can run on Windows 2012 and you'll have no problem at all.

Comment: A complication here is that opening a webSocket starts as an http request on the same port.  So, you can't simply proxy all incoming webSocket requests on port 80 over to your other server - it's a little more complicated than that.  instead, you'd have to have a proxy that was smart enough to see the http request that is actually the first step in opening a webSocket and forward that, but not forward other web requests.  This likely can be done, but it's a little more complicated than a simple proxy.

Comment: You cannot have two different processes listening concurrently on the same port. That is, even with the "SO_REUSEADDR" option and its relatives, any given traffic will only go to _one_ socket. You need a reliable way of diverting your WebSocket traffic to the WebSocket server while keeping your normal HTTP traffic for your web server on the old server. I suppose one option would be to run the WebSocket server on port 80, and have it _also_ act as a proxy, forwarding traffic to your IIS instance when it (however) decides the traffic isn't valid WebSocket traffic. But, ugh.